# looping a program that converts to uppercase and shifts 4 letter grades in C

Tags: c

This program calls two functions uppercase(), which converts the input to uppercase, and shift(), which shifts the grade input.

Here's my uppercase() function:

```
void uppercase(char *p)
{

 if(islower(*p)) {
    *p = toupper(*p);
    }

}
```

Here's the shift() function:

```
void shift(char *p1, char *p2, char *p3, char *p4)
{
 int count = 0;
 do {
 ++count;
 char tmp;
 tmp = *p4;
 *p4 = *p3;
 *p3 = *p2;
 *p2 = *p1;
 *p1 = tmp;
 printf("Grades Shifted #%i:   %c %c %c %c \n", count, *p1, *p2, *p3, *p4);
 } while (count < 4);

}
```

Here's my main function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
main (void)
{
 float choice;

 do {
 char c1, c2, c3, c4;
 printf ("Enter 4 letter grades to find statistics: ");
 scanf("%c %c %c %c", &c1, &c2, &c3, &c4);
 getchar();

 uppercase(&c1);
 uppercase(&c2);
 uppercase(&c3);
 uppercase(&c4);

 printf("Input Grades: %c %c %c %c\n", c1, c2, c3, c4);
 shift(&c1, &c2, &c3, &c4);
 printf("Want to shift more grades (y/n)? ");
 choice = getchar();    
 } while ( choice == 'y' || choice == 'Y');
getchar();

}
```

My output looks like this

> Enter 4 letter grades to find statistics: abcd
>   Input Grades: A B C D
>   Grades Shifted #1:   D A B C
>   Grades Shifted #2:   C D A B
>   Grades Shifted #3:   B C D A
>   Grades Shifted #4:   A B C D
>   Want to shift more grades (y/n)? y
>   Enter 4 letter grades to find statistics: adff
>   Input Grades:
>    A D F
>   Grades Shifted #1:   F
>    A D
>   Grades Shifted #2:   D F
>    A
>   Grades Shifted #3:   A D F
>   Grades Shifted #4:
>    A D F
>   Want to shift more grades (y/n)?

The format gets messed up on the second input, and when I input another y after the second input, the program closes. I've been tinkering with this for the past hour and I can't figure out why my formatting gets messed up or why the loop closes/crashes on the third attempt.

Also how can I make it so that my main function only accepts inputs of A-D or F.

Thanks.

Comment: why is choice a float?

Comment: @OsamaJaved I saw someone do that somewhere and assumed it was something I had to do. Should I change it to just a char?

Comment: Yes change it to a `char`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's because you have a new line sitting in your getchar() input

When you enter 'y' then press enter, you're getting "y\n".

Clear the input when re-entering the do while loop

```
printf("Want to shift more grades (y/n)? ");
choice = getchar();
c = getchar();
while (c != '\n' && c != EOF)
  c = getchar();
} while ( choice == 'y' || choice == 'Y');
```

For your second question:

You need to check the values of c1,c2,c3,c4 luckily there's a function for that

```
while( !(isalpha(c1) && isalpha(c2) && isalpha(c3) && isalpha(c4)) )
  printf ("Enter 4 letter grades to find statistics: ");
  scanf("%c %c %c %c", &c1, &c2, &c3, &c4);
  getchar();
```

Note that the isalpha function simply checks the value of each character... here's an ascii table, notice where A-Z and a-z are. http://www.asciitable.com/

---

scanf/getchar() line clearing: http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t318260-peek-at-stdin-flush-stdin.html

Comment: This solved my problem. Thank you. What does this part do? `while (c != '\n' && c != EOF)` I'm not sure how a new line was "siting in my getchar() input" can you point that out for me please?

Comment: It keeps calling getchar() until it reads a newline (enter in Linux/Unix) or EOF (end of file, which is -1 I believe)

Answer (score 0):

you can use scanf() instead of getchar() as scanf will stop until it reaches a whitespace